# Make new users automatically approved

Tags: users, user-registration, membership

I'm allowing new user registrations on my site and checked "Anyone can register" and set the default role to Subscriber, but for some reason users still need manual approval. This is annoying because people will sign up but not be able to log in.

No matter what I do users go into the database as Unapproved. I've checked with my host and they haven't put any extra security features in place so I don't know why this is happening. I thought "approved" was the default WordPress behaviour for new users if you allow it?

Essentially, I want to automatically Approve new users.

Any ideas? I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. I had Absolute Privacy plugin turned on and that was interfering.